# Problems coloring features of file geodatabase in QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal, file-geodatabase

I managed to open a file geodatabase (.gdb) in QGIS. The extensions of my data are correctly shown and the attribute table shows all values correctly. However, when I double-click on the layer to color a specific column based on its values it does not classify the values as it used to with normal shapefiles. I attached a picture to show what I mean. 
Opening the attribute table and clicking on a random row does highlight the specific feature on the map so I assume the data is read in correctly.
Any idea on what to improve?
I use Qgis 2.8 and gdal 1.11.2 on Ubuntu 14.04

[image]

Comment: That is strange.  It works for me on Windows 7, QGIS 2.6.

Comment: I tried with a different database and got the same result. Plotting the data in R seems to work as expected but is very slow. So I think this is QGIS related.